# What's the difference between "imbalance" and "unbalance"?

Tags: differences, nouns

Is there a difference in usage between *imbalance* and *unbalance* as nouns?

Specifically, we are designing a product where we measure three (3) related quantities continuously. These three quantities are normally within a reasonable percentage of each other. If there is a large difference, should that be shown as *parameter imbalance* or *parameter unbalance*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In common usage, *imbalance* is the noun meaning the state of being not balanced, while *unbalance* is the verb meaning to cause the loss of balance. In the context stated, the noun form should be used.

Comment: The Oxford dictionary specifies this in the meaning of unbalance as a noun:
n. L19. [f. UN-1 + BALANCE n.] Lack of balance

Comment: @VaibhavGarg I checked my Oxford dictionary, 7th edition and it clearly states that "unbalance" is a verb. and the examples cited also support that
Here is a link of the screenshot
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10934250_10153044839088966_1882668967_n.jpg?oh=4484e3fc3404c9e19ca675a5df562b67&oe=54C370C5&__gda__=1422080296_7052ef61686252afcd3a80f56a66359c

Answer (score 1):

Imbalance is what you want.

Comment: Can You explain please?

Comment: No one says "unbalance" nowadays. The noun used is invariably "imbalance." Probably because it's easier to say.

Comment: The adjective form allows 'unbalanced' though: ["He's deranged, mentally unbalanced."](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mentally+unbalanced%2C+mentally+imbalanced&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: But the OP wants a noun.

Answer (score 0):

*Imbalance* should be used to describe procedures, regulations, laws, labour. E.g., one can say in a work environment, "I am executing the same job as you and producing more  positive results than you but yet you earn a higher salary".

*Unbalance* should be used to describe issues of a more  physical nature, e.g. "your tyres in your car is unbalanced therefore you are experiencing a rugged ride", or "there is an umbalance in our weather and climate conditions due to global warming".

*Imbalance* and *unbalance* are  adjectives. *Balance* can be used as a verb, e.g. "balance yourself on  your bike or  you could have a nasty accident", can also be used as a noun. There are many variations depending on the related context.

Comment: No, *inbalance* and *unbalance* without the *-d* on the end are typically used as nouns or verbs, not as adjectives.  Only when you add a *-d* to those two words do they become adjectives: *unbalanced*. Also, you have a typo, at one point misspelling *unbalance* with an *m* for its first *n*.